# Hiding Label via CSS

Tags: css, labels

I'm trying to hide some text and a checkbox on this URL: https://bndlstech.com/wholesale-registration-form/

Specifically, I'm trying to hide the "Copy from Billing Address" text and checkbox. This is currently being added to the page via a WooCommerce Wholesale plugin.

This is what the code currently looks like:

```
<label for="wwp_wholesaler_copy_billing_address">Copy from billing address</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="wwp_wholesaler_copy_billing_address" id="wwp_wholesaler_copy_billing_address" value="yes">
```

I was successfully able to hide the checkbox by adding this CSS:

```
#wwp_wholesaler_copy_billing_address { display: none;}
```

But I'm having trouble removing the label "Copy from Billing Address".

I tried using this CSS, but it isn't working:

```
label[for="wwp_wholesaler_copy_billing_address"] 
{ display: none;}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Where were you putting that `label` CSS block? I just tried adding it to a random CSS file in Chrome's dev tools and it disappeared. Also make sure you clear your cache and hard reload after making CSS changes (and if the CSS is enqueued in WordPress, ensure you're changing the version parameter to `wp_enqueue_style`)

Answer (score 1):

remove the quotation marks so it looks like the following

```
label[for=wwp_wholesaler_copy_billing_address] {
    display: none;
}
```

Try that and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Removing the quotation marks worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Celador - super. Glad it worked for you.